# Java, Handling CSV file, access individual columns?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

So, I have a csv file that goes something like this

```
Id | Stamp | Date    | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
01 | 14E+  | 2011/05 | 333     | 312     | 457
02 | 15T+  | 2011/05 | 432     | 345     | 354
```

etc. 
So, I have written a program that uses the JFileChooser and opens this csv file, stores it into a file, reads it and displays it into a text area. What I want to do (if I can fix the program) is basically remove the ID Stamp and Date colums, then parse the data into doubles so that I can find the average from value 1, value 2 and value 3. Can someone please help me understand how to do this? I don't not understand the CSV fiel handling well at all.

program
http://gyazo.com/b57563c6dfde12ec838584b8a93fdbb8

csv file
http://gyazo.com/3b6dfa366df7d6d57a7c81e757e07db6

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;//Importing any required tools.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CSVFiles extends JFrame { //Class, inherits properties of the JFrame. 

    private JPanel contentPane; //Create a container for the GUI.
    //Create other components used in the GUI
    private JTextField maxTxtVCC;
    private JTextField maxTxtTemp;
    private JTextField maxTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtLight;
    private JTextField avTxtLight;
    private JTextField minTxtTemp;
    private JTextField avTxtTemp;
    private JTextField minTxtVCC;
    private JTextField avTxtVCC;
    private JButton btnMax;
    private JButton btnMin;
    private JButton btnAv;
    private JTextField opnTxt;
    private JButton btnOpn;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private JFileChooser fc; 

    private String content = "";
    String [] contentCSV = new String [53000]; //String array to hold the data, 2000 gives more than enough space
    int totalValues; //Used to hold the amount of values in the array (52790 ish)

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main method
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { //Create a runnable method
                try {
                    CSVFiles frame = new CSVFiles(); //Launch the GUI
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); //Print errors
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CSVFiles() { //Open constructor

        super ("CSV Files"); //Create a title for the GUI

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Instruct how the GUI is closed
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600); //Set size and location
        contentPane = new JPanel(); //Declare the JPanel
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); //Create a boarder
        setContentPane(contentPane); //Add the JPanel
        contentPane.setLayout(null); //Set the layout

        maxTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtVCC.setBounds(113, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtTemp.setBounds(113, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        maxTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        maxTxtLight.setBounds(113, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        maxTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(maxTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblLight = new JLabel("Light"); //Declare this label
        lblLight.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblLight.setBounds(22, 469, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblLight); //Add to the content pane

        JLabel lblTemp = new JLabel("Temperature"); //Declare this label
        lblTemp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblTemp.setBounds(10, 503, 109, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblTemp);

        JLabel lblVCC = new JLabel("VCC"); //Declare this label
        lblVCC.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); //Set the font and size of text
        lblVCC.setBounds(22, 534, 46, 17); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(lblVCC); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtLight.setBounds(221, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtLight = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtLight.setBounds(331, 472, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtLight.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtLight); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtTemp.setBounds(221, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtTemp = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtTemp.setBounds(331, 503, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtTemp.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtTemp); //Add to the content pane

        minTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        minTxtVCC.setBounds(221, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        minTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(minTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        avTxtVCC = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        avTxtVCC.setBounds(331, 534, 86, 20); //Set size and location
        avTxtVCC.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(avTxtVCC); //Add to the content pane

        btnMax = new JButton("Maximum"); //Declare this button
        btnMax.setBounds(110, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMax); //Add to the content pane

        btnMin = new JButton("Minimum"); //Declare this button
        btnMin.setBounds(221, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnMin); //Add to the content pane

        btnAv = new JButton("Average"); //Declare this button
        btnAv.setBounds(328, 438, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnAv); //Add to the content pane

        textArea = new TextArea(); //Declare this text area
        textArea.setBounds(22, 55, 551, 367); //Set size and location
        textArea.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(textArea); //Add to the content pane

        btnOpn = new JButton("Open File"); //Declare this button
        btnOpn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Add an action listener to this button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Method for action performed
                try{
                    fc = new JFileChooser(); //Declare the file chooser
                    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv")); //Add a filter for only choosing CSV files
                    fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter()); //Remove option to select any file type

                    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane); // Open the file chooser
                    File f; //Create a file to hold the data

                    //If the selected file is approved by the file chooser...
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        f = fc.getSelectedFile(); //Stored selected file into file variable

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                        String line = null;

                        textArea.append("Opening "+ f.getAbsolutePath()); //Print out file path
                        textArea.append("\nLoading file...\n\n");  //Print out loading message and some new lines

                        in.readLine(); //Skip the first line as it's just headers
                        int index = 0; //Integer used to label the indexes of the array


                            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                                content += line+"\n"; //+= Add left operand to right, so "" + line, then new line
                                contentCSV[index] = line; //Storing each line of the file into the array and assigning the indexs
                                ++index; //increment the index to move the next one up for hte next line
                            }


                        totalValues = index;
                        textArea.append(content);
                        textArea.append("\n*** End of File"); //Print the file onto the text area and an end of file message

                    }
                    else{
                        f = null;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
        btnOpn.setBounds(484, 26, 89, 23); //Set size and location
        contentPane.add(btnOpn); //Add to the content pane

        opnTxt = new JTextField(); //Declare this text field
        opnTxt.setBounds(22, 27, 452, 20); //Set size and location
        opnTxt.setEditable(false); //Set it so it cannot be edited
        contentPane.add(opnTxt); //Add to the content pane
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not read each line of the file into a String, use string.split("|") to split the string into an array of all the elements, then calculate the average of the elements your interested in?

Comment: Please do not append strings in a loop like you are doing for `content`. Use a `StringBuilder` instead. Also the UI freezes because of the amount of processing you are doing on the same thread as the UI thread. It hangs the UI can't update itself when you are parsing the large CSV.

Comment: I want to split the data up then do the calculation of each element I am interested in, that's what I don't understand how to do. I want to calculate the average of the three value columns, but dunno how to calculate just those and void the other columns. Also, I don't know the StringBuilder. I will have to look that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With apologies to Satheesh Cheveri, I am removing some of the bugs in his suggestion.

```
String cols[] = line.split("\\|"); // since the argument to split is a regex and | is a special character, it must be quoted.
double v1 = Double.parseDouble(cols[3]);
double v2 = Double.parseDouble(cols[4]);
double v3 = Double.parseDouble(cols[5]);
handleValuesFromLine(v1, v2, v3);  // accumulate stuff for averaging later
```

I would also recommend that you do an Extract Method to create a

```
loadDataFromFile(BufferedReader in)
```

method.  That way you can write a second app to test your file parsing logic without having to run a GUI and click on 5 things just to test a code change.

Comment: Brillant, I just did this, then printed v1 to the console and check it against my CSV file, it was spot on. Can use this to do what I need to do, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = line // 

String cols[] = content.split("\\|");
String v1 = cols[3];
String v2 = cols[4];
String v3 = cols[5];
String dt = cols[2]
```

Convert splitted values to int values using Integer.parseInt/Double.parseDouble and do average out and date value can be parsed to date using `DateFormat`